# Are ignition coils easy to replace on a BMW 318i 2.0L 2007 msport model?

Tags: bmw, sparkplugs, misfire, diy, ignition-coil

They'll cost me £21.06 each. I watched a video on YouTube that showed a guy clipping of the engine cover and pulling out and plugging in the coils. I'm not 100% sure what BMW model this was but it looked fairly straight forward.

If it's easier than putting together an exercise power rack then I'd like to have a crack at it and save myself some money. My mechanic is good at stretching labour charges.

I've heard there is a particular set I need to avoid. Any advice on this too? I've been quoted on a set of bosch ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a basic set of hand tools (ratchet/socket set). I don't know what it involves to get any covers off (may require some torx sockets or drivers to remove, though is probably only connected by some 10mm bolts or fasteners). The coil itself is a "coil-on" configuration which, in and of itself, does not require any tools to remove. You flip the small piece which holds the wires in place (easily seen on a replacement coil), detach the wire connector, pull on the coil while giving it a little twist and it should pull right out. Replace it with the new one and you should be golden. Put a small amount of dielectric grease inside the boot side (which connects to the spark plug) of the new coil before installation. This will help it from sticking when you want to replace the spark plugs. If you are changing more than one coil, do it one at a time. It really shouldn't be hard to do. Just keep track of your parts you pull off (engine cover, bolts, etc).

I found what appears to be good instructions [here](http://www.pelicanparts.com/BMW/techarticles/BMW-3-Series-E90/ENGINE-Spark_Plug_Coil_Replacement/ENGINE-Spark_Plug_Coil_Replacement.htm) (though it shows a 6-cyl model) and a [video of an older model](http://youtu.be/B_012eIMKf0) where the guy is replacing the spark plugs. This may be useful for removal of any engine covers. Hope this helps.

Comment: It happened to be very easy. I went to a mechanic who worked on my previous BMW. Very cool guy. Advised me not buy anything without having a diagnostic test so I would be 100% sure about what to drive. He gave me a diagnostic test for free and ignition coil 4 came up. He showed me what to do so next time I could do it myself. Replaced a faulty bulb and t-cut my bonnet to get off some sticky stuff. Purchased only 1 ignition coil and he charged me a total of £50. The ignition coil was £18.50 including Vat so his labour cost was less than £40 and the car drive great. Very happy.

Comment: @LondonGuy ... From what I could tell, this looked pretty easy. Sounds like you got a good deal from your mechanic. Hard to find people like that you can trust these days, so you may want to stay with him. Doesn't hurt getting "second opinions" though, even if they are online opinions :D

Comment: He was my third of the day. The previous 2 wanted me to buy all 4 ignition coils without doing a diagnostic test. One said £70 for the test and £90 labour. The other just said "we'll talk".  I will definitely be sticking with this mechanic. Very honest and a clean worker. He cleared the errors for me too. Although my brake pads light is on. I will sort that when my service comes up as the brakes are still very sharp.

Answer (score 1):

BMW TIS details the instructions (I assume your engine is an N46):

- [Remove the ignition coil covers](http://workshop-manuals.com/bmw/3_series_e90/318i_n46_sal/2_repair_instructions/12__engine_electrical_system_%28n46%29/13__ignition_coil/2_ra__removing_ignition_coil_cover_%28n46t%29/)
- [Remove the ignition coils](http://workshop-manuals.com/bmw/3_series_e90/318i_n46_sal/2_repair_instructions/12__engine_electrical_system_%28n46%29/13__ignition_coil/5_ra__replacing_ignition_coils_%28n42_n40_n46_n45%29/)

Judging by the instructions it should be a breeze (at least easier than my S62!)

Comment: Quite easy as I watched my mechanic do it today. Next time I can do this myself. Just need a good tool set.